# Add two UITextFields to UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I add two `UITextField`s to a `UIToolbar` like below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Beer said!
Look at your picture given, I think it's not a UIToolbar with two UITextFields. If you want to use UIToolbar, you can write it without IB. The codes like following:

```
UIToolbar *tool = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0,0.0,400,180.0)];
UITextField *firstTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 360.0, 60)];
firstTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[firstTextField.layer setCornerRadius:18];
UITextField *secondTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 100.0, 360.0, 60)];
secondTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[secondTextField.layer setCornerRadius:18];
secondTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;

[tool addSubview:firstTextField];
[tool addSubview:secondTextField];

[view addSubview:tool];
[tool release];
[firstTextField release];
[secondTextField release];
```

You can change the style of the UIToolBar and UITextFields.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IB to add the UIToolbar to the view all you need to do is drag the UITextField onto the UIToolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't with standard UIToolbar. It's a one-row thing.

But you can add them to a UIView where you paint the gradient as background. Have a look at UIView and Core Graphics.